# ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION - when calling a procedure inside while loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, cursor, procedure

I'm getting the error when my procedure is trying to call another procedure in while loop. Also, when the error comes inside the while loop, it should skip for next iteration after logging it, but the below comes out of the loop. Could someone please help me on this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NUMBERS
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DECLARE VARIABLES
    UPDATE log_1 table

    DECLARE CURSOR FOR SELECT ANYTHING
    OPEN CURUPD 

    FETCH NEXT FROM CURUPD INTO VARIABLES
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY 
            UPDATE TABLE BASED ON VARIABLES
    
            EXEC procedure_2 VARIABLES
    
            INSERT TABLE BASED ON VARIABLES
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            Update Log_2 Table
                SCount = SCount-1;
                FCount = Fcount+1;
        END CATCH
        SCount = SCount+1;
        FETCH NEXT FROM CURUPD INTO VARIABLES
    END 
    CLOSE CUR
    DEALLOCATE CUR

    UPDATE LOG_1;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    UPDATE LOG_1 Table
END CATCH
```

Comment: I'm not going to pretend to understand any of that - it gives a whole bunch of syntax errors when I put it in SSMS. However I can comment that its often worth/necessary to check `@@TRANCOUNT` before committing/rolling back a transaction to ensure one exists.

Comment: So If I'm calling a procedure in my while loop, it will be a seperate transaction for that particular procedure. How will I be able to save the transactions that happened before calling my stored procedure in while loop. Also, I want to commit my code once the entire process for that particular iteration is done.. I don't want to commit the code in between so, if there is an error, I can simply rollback the changes.

Comment: Suggested reading: [Handling Transactions in Nested SQL Server Stored Procedures](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4897/handling-transactions-in-nested-sql-server-stored-procedures/).

Comment: So If I commit my transactions at each part of the code let's say before calling the procedure, inside the second procedure, and if I get an error while executing the insert statement after the procedure, then I will not be able to rollback the changes. How can I handle this part?

Comment: Do you really need a cover all transaction and individual transactions per SP call? Or can you just have them inside the SP? And have you considered using [savepoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/save-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I'd love to know *why* you need a cursor here, and why `procedure_2` doesn't take a TVP input

Comment: @Charlieface TVP Input?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15 But we don't know what it does, if it does no modification it is probably better as an [**inline** Table valued Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#TVF)

Answer (score 0):

We do not know what code is inside your `procedure_2`. Probably there is a transaction in this code.

You must understand that **a transaction is a state of a session**, and *there is no possibility, by definition, to have many transactions entangled* in the different code of the different procedures.

By definition, because a transaction is an atomic execution of code. Can an atom be non atomic? Can a transaction have "subtransactions"?

Because Microsoft SQL Server supports nested transaction, the count of `BEGIN TRANSACTION` is very important to know when you need to execute a `COMMIT` or a `ROLLBACK`.

SQL Server uses the asymmetric model of nested transaction:

1. The first `ROLLBACK` ends the transaction by a cancel and removes all the modifications
2. The last `COMMIT` (in equivalent number of `BEGIN TRAN`) ends the
   transaction and accepts finally all the database modifications

You have two different manner to have code that manages correctly this behaviour.

1. Is to read `@@TRANCOUNT` to decide if you have to execute a `ROLLBACK`
   or `COMMIT`
2. Is to know if the transaction is alive with the integrated function
   `XACT_STATE()`

I prefer the last one, and the code template to do so must be this one:

```
-- non excepted an non transactionned code
BEGIN TRY
   -- non transactionned code, but excepted
   BEGIN TRANSACTION
   -- transactionned and excepted code
   COMMIT; --> to accept all modification
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 --> is the transaction alive ?
      ROLLBACK; --> yes ! cancel it
   THROW; --> throw an new exception identical that the one that causes the CATCH to inform outsided procedures
END CATCH
```

That you have to put in every procedure.

If you don't do that, you will have the error message you have put in the title.